Azure pipelines error: [warning]Failed to download task 'CmdLine'. Error Unable to read data from the transport connection: Connection reset by peer
I created a pipeline as below:
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - pre-prod

pool:
  name: default

stages:
- stage: build
  displayName: 'Build stage'
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: 'Build'
    steps:
    - script: echo Build starting
    - script: |
        docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml build
      displayName: 'Build Docker images'

Installed and registered azure agent on my ubuntu server.
by running the run.sh, it connects to the server properly and starts processing the job as expected.
looking at the logs, there's a stage named initialize job which is apparently trying to download the CmdLine task and is throwing an error:
##[warning]Failed to download task 'CmdLine'. Error Unable to read data from the transport connection: Connection reset by peer.
##[warning]Inner Exception: Connection reset by peer
##[warning]Back off 21.485 seconds before retry.
##[warning]Failed to download task 'CmdLine'. Error Unable to read data from the transport connection: Connection reset by peer.
##[warning]Inner Exception: Connection reset by peer
##[warning]Back off 27.578 seconds before retry.
##[warning]Failed to download task 'CmdLine'. Error Unable to read data from the transport connection: Connection reset by peer.
##[warning]Inner Exception: Connection reset by peer
##[error]Unable to read data from the transport connection: Connection reset by peer.

I also tried setting DNS as the ubuntu machine is placed in a restricted country, but didn't work.
Note: As I am an absolute beginner to this, I would like to kindly ask not to vote this question as dislike so it won't be removed.
Also if there's any other approached you think might be helpful, please don't hesitate to share.

These kind of situations might occur when there are issues in Azure DevOps or there are connectivity/networking issues on your side.

See Troubleshoot pipeline runs and Review logs

May i know if you are using On-Prem ADO server(version?) or Azure DevOps cloud service? The error indicates it's a network connection issue from agent to DevOps server/service. If it's ADO sever, it's recommended to put the agent in the same network with server. Or you could contact your IT admin to help check if the network is complicated.

I am actually using On-Prem server

@rezajafari, the task version will not automatically sync with marketplace if you are using on-prem server. The task exists on the agent folder _work\tasks, you can copy from another working agent not from github. You need to have a working agent to copy from. The best way is to resolve the network to server.

As per the pipeline execution run documentation, before a pipeline executes the Initialize Job task analyzes the task definitions that appear in the pipeline and then downloads them to the build agent's cache directory. The script task is an alias for the CmdLine task.
The unable to read data from the transport connection error message implies that your self-hosted agent is unable to communicate with the destination. You mentioned your ubuntu server is in a restricted country, so chances are it's being blocked at the destination.
The list of Azure DevOps related IP address ranges and host names is documented here.

Thanks for your reply.
I was thinking of downloading the tasks manually on my server but don't really know how and where should I place those tasks.
I downloaded the repo https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks
but couldn't really apply packages.

I wouldn't advise this. There are 1000s of tasks in the marketplace and they are updated often, that's why the agent downloads them.
